# JUnit5 test void method. Get org.opentest4j.AssertionFailedError: expected:

Tags: java, junit5

Don't judge my code, I am beginner. In the future, I'll refactor it.

I would like to ask for help writing JUnit5 unit tests.

I need to test my class Formatter

```
package com.*.text;

import com.*.math.Divider;
import com.*.model.Result;

/**
 * text sub package - for formatters
 */

public class Formatter {
    Result result;
    Divider divider;
    private int firstIndexPartialDividend = 0; // find the beginning of the number
    private int countSpace = 0; // space counter

    public Formatter(Result result) {
        this.result = result;
        this.divider = new Divider(result);
    }

    public void format() {
        // print the first row
        printFirstRow();
        String dividendText = Integer.toString(result.getDividend());
        for (int i = 1; i <= dividendText.length(); i++) {
            result.setFirstPartialDividend(Integer.parseInt(dividendText.substring(firstIndexPartialDividend, i)));
            // print the second row
            if (result.getFirstPartialDividend() >= result.getDivisor()
                    && firstIndexPartialDividend == 0) {
                countSpace = dividendText.length() - i;
                printSecondRow(result.getFirstPartialDividend());
                result.setRemainder(result.getFirstPartialDividend()
                        - result.getProduct());
                firstIndexPartialDividend = i;
                // To align the space in the next row.
                if (Integer.toString(result.getProduct()).length()
                        > Integer.toString(result.getRemainder()).length()
                        && result.getRemainder() > 0) {
                    countSpace = Integer.toString(result.getProduct()).length()
                            - Integer.toString(result.getRemainder()).length();
                } else {
                    countSpace = 0;
                }
                // print following row
            } else if (firstIndexPartialDividend > 0) {
                if (Integer.toString(result.getProduct()).length() / 2
                        == Integer.toString(result.getRemainder()).length()
                        && Integer.toString(result.getRemainder()).length() > 1) {
                    countSpace++;
                }
                int nextPartialDividend
                        = Integer.parseInt(Integer.toString(result.getRemainder())
                        + dividendText.substring(firstIndexPartialDividend, i));
                printFollowingRow(nextPartialDividend, dividendText, i);
                // print last row
                printLastRow(dividendText, i);
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * printFirstRow method - print the first row of an application
     */
    public void printFirstRow() {
        System.out.printf("%d|%d\n", result.getDividend(), result.getDivisor());
    }

    /**
     * printSecondRow method - print the second row of an application
     */
    public void printSecondRow(int firstPartialDividend) {
        divider.calculateProduct(firstPartialDividend);
        System.out.println(result.getProduct() + getSpace(countSpace) + "|"
                + (result.getQuotient()));
    }

    /**
     * printFollowingRow method - print all following row of an application
     * except for the last row
     */
    public void printFollowingRow(int nextPartialDividend, String dividendText, int i) {
        if (nextPartialDividend >= result.getDivisor()) {
            divider.calculateProduct(nextPartialDividend);
            alignFollowingRowSpace(nextPartialDividend, dividendText, i);
            result.setRemainder(nextPartialDividend - result.getProduct());
            firstIndexPartialDividend = i;
        }
    }

    /**
     * alignFollowingRowSpace method - align following rows by space
     */
    public void alignFollowingRowSpace(int nextPartialDividend, String dividendText, int i) {
        if (Integer.toString(nextPartialDividend).length()
                > 0 && result.getRemainder() > 0) {
            if (Integer.toString(result.getProduct()).length()
                    != Integer.toString(nextPartialDividend).length()) {
                if (i == dividendText.length()) {
                    countSpace = Integer.toString(result.getProduct()).length()
                            - Integer.toString(result.getRemainder()).length();
                } else {
                    countSpace = Integer.toString(result.getProduct()).length()
                            - Integer.toString(result.getRemainder()).length()
                            + countSpace;
                }
                System.out.println(getSpace(countSpace) + nextPartialDividend);
                countSpace++;
                System.out.println(getSpace(countSpace) + result.getProduct());
                countSpace--;
            } else if (Integer.toString(nextPartialDividend).length()
                    != Integer.toString(result.getRemainder()).length()
                    && Integer.toString(result.getRemainder()).length() > 0) {
                System.out.println(getSpace(countSpace) + nextPartialDividend);
                System.out.println(getSpace(countSpace) + result.getProduct());
                if (Integer.toString(nextPartialDividend).length()
                        == Integer.toString(nextPartialDividend - result.getProduct()).length()
                        && Integer.toString(result.getProduct()).length()
                        == Integer.toString(nextPartialDividend - result.getProduct()).length()) {
                    // Stub for save value countSpace
                } else {
                    countSpace++;
                }
            } else {
                countSpace = Integer.toString(result.getProduct()).length()
                        - Integer.toString(result.getRemainder()).length()
                        + countSpace;
                System.out.println(getSpace(countSpace) + nextPartialDividend);
                System.out.println(getSpace(countSpace) + result.getProduct());
            }
        } else if (Integer.toString(nextPartialDividend).length() > 0
                && result.getRemainder() == 0) {
            countSpace = Integer.toString(result.getProduct()).length()
                    + countSpace;
            System.out.println(getSpace(countSpace) + nextPartialDividend);
            System.out.println(getSpace(countSpace) + result.getProduct());
        }
    }

    /**
     * printLastRow method - print the last line of the application
     */
    public void printLastRow(String dividendText, int i) {
        if (i == dividendText.length() && result.getRemainder() > 0) {
            countSpace = dividendText.length() - Integer.toString(result.getRemainder()).length();
            System.out.println(getSpace(countSpace) + result.getRemainder());
        } else if (i == dividendText.length()) {
            countSpace = dividendText.length() - dividendText.substring(firstIndexPartialDividend, i).length();
            System.out.println(getSpace(countSpace) + dividendText.substring(firstIndexPartialDividend, i));
        }
    }

    /**
     * getSpace method to get the number of spaces you want
     */
    public String getSpace(int count) {
        String space = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
            space += " ";
        return space;
    }
}
```

The main task of the class is to print the result of long division

Something like this

```
78454|4
4    |19613
38
36
 24
 24
   5
   4
   14
   12
    2
```

I wrote a test

```
package com.*.text;


import com.*.math.Divider;
import com.*.model.Result;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeEach;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.PrintStream;

import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertEquals;

public class FormatterTest {
    Result result;
    Divider divider;
    Formatter formatter;
    private final ByteArrayOutputStream outputStreamCaptor = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

    @BeforeEach
    public void setUp(){
        System.setOut(new PrintStream(outputStreamCaptor));
        this.result = new Result();
        this.formatter = new Formatter(this.result);
        this.divider = new Divider(result);
        String[] testArray = new String[] {"78454", "4"};
        this.divider.divide(Integer.parseInt(testArray[0]), Integer.parseInt(testArray[1]));
    }

    @Test
    void format() {
        String expectedResult = "78454|4\n4    |19613\n38\n36\n 24\n 24\n   5\n   4\n   14\n   12\n    2";

        formatter.format();
        String actualResult = outputStreamCaptor.toString().trim();

        assertEquals(expectedResult, actualResult);
    }
}
```

My test throws an error but outputs what is displayed is what it expects

```
expected: <78454|4
4    |19613
38
36
 24
 24
   5
   4
   14
   12
    2> but was: <78454|4
4    |19613
38
36
 24
 24
   5
   4
   14
   12
    2>
<Click to see difference>

org.opentest4j.AssertionFailedError: expected: <78454|4
4    |19613
38
36
 24
 24
   5
   4
   14
   12
    2> but was: <78454|4
4    |19613
38
36
 24
 24
   5
   4
   14
   12
    2>
    at app//org.junit.jupiter.api.AssertionUtils.fail(AssertionUtils.java:55)
    at app//org.junit.jupiter.api.AssertionUtils.failNotEqual(AssertionUtils.java:62)
    at app//org.junit.jupiter.api.AssertEquals.assertEquals(AssertEquals.java:182)
    at app//org.junit.jupiter.api.AssertEquals.assertEquals(AssertEquals.java:177)
    at app//org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertEquals(Assertions.java:1124)
    at app//com.gmail.smaglenko.division.text.FormatterTest.format(FormatterTest.java:37)
    at java.base@16.0.2/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base@16.0.2/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:78)
    at java.base@16.0.2/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base@16.0.2/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
    at app//org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:686)
    at app//org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.MethodInvocation.proceed(MethodInvocation.java:60)
    at app//org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$ValidatingInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:131)
    at app//org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.intercept(TimeoutExtension.java:149)
    at app//org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestableMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:140)
    at app//org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:84)
    at app//org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker$ReflectiveInterceptorCall.lambda$ofVoidMethod$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:115)
    at app//org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.lambda$invoke$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:105)
    at app//org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$InterceptedInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:106)
    at app//org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:64)
    at app//org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.chainAndInvoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:45)
    at app//org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.invoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:37)
    at app//org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:104)
    at app//org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:98)
    at app//org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestMethod$6(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:205)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at app//org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeTestMethod(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:201)
    at app//org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:137)
    at app//org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:71)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:135)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:125)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:135)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:123)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:122)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:80)
    at java.base@16.0.2/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:125)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:135)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:123)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:122)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:80)
    at java.base@16.0.2/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:125)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:135)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:123)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:122)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:80)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:32)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:51)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:108)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:88)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.lambda$execute$0(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:54)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.withInterceptedStreams(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:67)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:52)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:96)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:75)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor$CollectAllTestClassesExecutor.processAllTestClasses(JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.java:99)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor$CollectAllTestClassesExecutor.access$000(JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.java:79)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.stop(JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.java:75)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.SuiteTestClassProcessor.stop(SuiteTestClassProcessor.java:61)
    at java.base@16.0.2/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base@16.0.2/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:78)
    at java.base@16.0.2/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base@16.0.2/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:36)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ContextClassLoaderDispatch.dispatch(ContextClassLoaderDispatch.java:33)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:94)
    at jdk.proxy1/jdk.proxy1.$Proxy2.stop(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker$3.run(TestWorker.java:193)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.executeAndMaintainThreadName(TestWorker.java:129)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.execute(TestWorker.java:100)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.execute(TestWorker.java:60)
    at org.gradle.process.internal.worker.child.ActionExecutionWorker.execute(ActionExecutionWorker.java:56)
    at org.gradle.process.internal.worker.child.SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.call(SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.java:133)
    at org.gradle.process.internal.worker.child.SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.call(SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.java:71)
    at app//worker.org.gradle.process.internal.worker.GradleWorkerMain.run(GradleWorkerMain.java:69)
    at app//worker.org.gradle.process.internal.worker.GradleWorkerMain.main(GradleWorkerMain.java:74)


FormatterTest > format() FAILED
    org.opentest4j.AssertionFailedError at FormatterTest.java:37
```

When I click  I see message "contents are identical"
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EmNno.png)
I can't understand why it throws an error if contents are identical

Please share your ideas of what it could be

Is there some way to replace \r\n to \n?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Split the output into lines and validate it line by line. This will enable you to find the line with the error.

Comment: You can compare `expectedResult` and `actualCharacter` character by character. Maybe there are characters which are displayed graphically the same but their code are different. You can use this test https://gist.github.com/razafinarivohanania/1712c70518291fa9fcfbd2c7dc9e3213 to check it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem by putting the expected result in file result.xml

```
78454|4
4    |19613
38
36
 24
 24
   5
   4
   14
   12
    2
```

And add this in my test case

```
String expected = new String(getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("result.xml").readAllBytes());
```

Also helped to change all System.out.println to System.out.printf
and

```
String actualResult = outputStreamCaptor.toString().trim().replaceAll("\n" , "\r\n");
```

Comment: Honestly, this really won't help any future reader a lot. Focus on the **real** thing here: chars that cant be distinguished when just looking at a print out. Also note: Such an expected result testing ... that is super easy to break. Are you sure for example that your code and tests will only run under windows? Rather try to *abstract* what the formatter is doing, and make sure that you can check for *system specific* aspects in a system specific way.